# How to exact copy paint weights from one object to another

Tags: weight-painting

2 object occupying the same space with the exact same geometry.
They both need to be influence by one bone identically. I edited one's paint weight so I want to have the same changes applied to the other.

I was suggested to:
Select the object with the correct weight(source)
Shift select the object that you want to copy weights.
In weight paint hit [ Transfer Weights ]
 
Opens the Transfer Mesh Data tab.
hit [ Transfer Weights ] again.

**I tested it in pose mode but it didn't work they are still different.**

[image]

(UPDATE)
Upon additional information 
Hit [ Transfer Weights]
For Source Layer destination select: By Name
For Destination Layers Matching select: All layers
For Mix Mode select: Replace

Comment: Well, it should work. Check if the vertex group name is the same to the bone. If it still occurs, it is recommended that you share the blend file here, for much better review.

Comment: Here is the armature and the 2 object that I can't transfer paint weights.
http://www.filedropper.com/transferweightproblem

Comment: That's mainly because the verts are also weighed by parent bones, which controls different values between the two objects in your case. You can try to transfer weights for every group.

Comment: And, better use Topology mapping method when transfering in such case,  or you have to turn off the visibility of both amature modifiers.

Comment: I learned on Maya, seemed so simple to just hit Copy Skin Weights which I used all the time. I don't know how to transfer weights for every group. I googled topology mapping, what is it? Turn off visibility of a modifier? Leon makes me want to roll up in ball filled with regret for hoping to ever get Blender.

Comment: Haha, take it easy. for batch transfering vgroups between two exactly matched objs, you can always go to Vertex Group panel, in the "▼" menu, find **Copy Vertex Group to Selected**. That's it, and no data transfer used.

Comment: It works! And I get the concept. Thanks Leon. My greatest fear with Blender is asking for help, getting an answer that only eludes me and none knows how else to explain to me about something I have to understand how to use.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you can anwser your own question by what you get now. I bet it will help others in the future.  That's a nice way for us to learn from each other around.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 4 years old post but I've found a simpler solution with blender 2.82. So what I do is I copy the mesh that has three original vertex groups and arrange in the space where the 2nd mesh is meant to be at. Then rename the 2nd mesh's all vertex groups to different so it can retain its weight paint from original mesh. I used armature human rig default.